# Summary table from list

Tags: 2010

I've looked through previous Qs but am struggling.

I have a list with >100 entries and >20 columns, each entry is essentially a task with a Y/N check box at a number of stages.

What I want to do is have a smaller summary table counting the number of entries at stage a, b ,c etc.

I'd just use countif or similar in excel, however I don't have SP Designer or Enterprise - politics dictates so :( I'm on bog standard 2010.

This should be easy but it's really bugging me!!!

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create views of the list. Follow these steps -

1. In the list page of the -> go to the ribbon -> select `List`
2. Click on *Modify View*
3. Scroll down to the `totals` section. Change the value of the column you want to have a count of.
4. Go to `Group By` and select the column i.e. `stages`

That should get you the count of items grouped by stages.

---

Answer to your *cheeky* second question :)

Create Views :

1. Follow Step 1 as above, select *create view* this time -> select standard view
2. Set Name, scroll down and set filers if you want to.
3. Save the view.

Add view to the page :

1. create a site page /page. (go to site actions -> new page)
2. In the page, go to ribbon -> page -> Edit
3. Go to insert -> click on webpart -> choose your list.
4. The list with default view should come. Edit the webpart and set the view you want.
5. repeat step 3 and 4 for adding multiple views

Comment: Will have a go! Ty

Comment: Hi again! That looks good.  Can I add 2 views of the same list as two web parts? I.E one which has all details and then one which gives me the summary (I.E the one you provided the solution for)?

Comment: If this works, consider marking my response as the answer :)

Comment: Will do, I just added a cheeky 2nd Q to my comment ;)